# wav file running in localhost system but not in public ip in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, wav

I have alert code where I used alert.wav sound files, its working while I run code in local, but in the remote site (while opening in public IP) I'm not able to here alert sound. But in other systems (windows 7) its working, but not working on my windows 10 system.

```
if (x>y)
       {

       Response.Write("<embed height='0' width='0' src='/sounds/alert.wav' />");

       }
```

Comment: Did you check the network tab of your browser to see if it downloads the file?

Comment: yes its downloading the file and while opening the link of audio  file asking for save.

Comment: one thing you should do is check whether there's a correct mime type entry for .wav in IIS